# Read dotenv from bash script

Tags: bash

I have a bash file setting up a postgres-database.

```
#configure_db.sh
source ./secrets/sqlpassword.sh
createdb -U myuser mydatabase
```

I have a simple bash file exporting the password

```
#secrets/sqlpassword.sh
export PGPASSWORD='mypassword'
```

The rest of the node server uses environment variables saved in a .env-file. For the sake of order and simplicity i would want my postgres password stored in the same file:

```
//.env
postgrespassword='mypassword'
```

**How can you import a variable from a .env-file to as bash-file?**

**Is there another way of solving the above?**

Comment: Short of writing your own parser for the format you want to read, no.

Comment: Googling this problem immediately gets me a number of hits, including https://github.com/bashup/dotenv

Comment: Is the only thing you're missing the `export`? If so, we already have Q&A covering the topic. (Hint: `set -a` is your friend).

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you follow the same pattern?

Change

```
#configure_db.sh
source ./secrets/sqlpassword.sh
createdb -U myuser mydatabase
```

to

```
#configure_db.sh
PGPASSWORD=$(grep postgrespassword /path/to/.env | cut -d "=" -f2)
createdb -U myuser mydatabase
```

Comment: First thing the variable has to be named PGPASSWORD, as that is the environment variable that postgres will use. 

However, even with a correct name, when sourcing .env the variables aren't just read and exported. As commented by tripleee you probably need some kind of parser.

Comment: Excuse me i missunderstood. Maybe this is what you need?